# How close to the surface of the Sun would one have to be to determine an 'upright' position relative to it's surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, sun

As we stand upon the surface of the earth we're able to establish a relative 'up' and 'down' direction due to gravitational forces.  As we leave the confines of the earths gravitational attraction this firm axial understanding dissipates until we can float in whichever direction our velocities take us and this direction is just as equally up as it is down.  How close to the Sun must one be to walk 'upright'?

Comment: As long as you are in free fall, the distance doesn't matter, you would not be feeling any gravity. What allows us to determine up and down is the floor that we are standing on, i.e. we need something that stops us from falling freely in the gravity of a body. That has to be matter that stands still relative to the center of mass. In case of the sun that would probably be a rather dense plasma, i.e. already deep within the photosphere http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere, which has a density on the order of 2e-4kg/m^3, if not below that.

Comment: How far away do you think this distance is from Earth? If you're thinking the astronauts in the space station are far enough away, then there is a more serious misunderstanding here.

Comment: If you're in orbit,  you'll go into tidal lock sooner or later no matter how distant you are.

Comment: Given $ F = \frac{gMm}{r^2}$ , it's conceivable that, for a 'tall enough' person and a large enough star, once vertical the force on his feet would be significantly greater than the force on his head (even falling in, not in orbital tidal lock).

Comment: Surely, surely, surely one would simply assume there is a  fixed platform, at a given altitude, so as to answer this actually excellent "orders of magnitude" question.

Answer (score -1):

The sun is a ball of gas, so "relative to its surface" and "walk upright" are a bit of a problem. You might fire a rocket engine hard enough to balance the force of gravity, and stand still.

The acceleration of gravity gets weaker at large distance from the sun, but never is 0. $a = GM/r^2$.

So you could say it is gone when it is too small for you to detect. Or you could say it is gone when you are far enough that the gravity of other stars is equally strong.

Comment: in freefall, though, you can't detect these forces, equivalence principle etc

Comment: At what distance from the center of the sun, is, the force equivalent to the Earth's on the surface of the Earth?

Comment: @innisfree - Standing in a rocket that was thrusting hard enough to stay still is equivalent to standing on a surface in the sun's gravitational field. It would not be free fall unless the rocket was off.

Comment: @JoeBlow - $GM_S/r^2 = GM_E/R_E^2$. Or $r = r_E*\sqrt{M_S/M_E} = 3.68 *10^6 km$